# nsIProcess kill

Tags: javascript, firefox, process, kill

I'm launching an executable from a firefox extension successfully. When I attempt to kill that same process it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var process;
var loadingMonitor = {
    launchExternalApp : function (jnlp) {
        process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
        var env = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment);
        var javaWebStart = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
        javaWebStart.initWithPath(env.get("JAVA_HOME"));
        javaWebStart.append("bin");
        javaWebStart.append("javaws.exe"); //TODO fix this for linux and others http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid08E6670AF783B7BD5703D3378E5C9BB039326190.aspx?s=checkbox

        process.init(javaWebStart);

        var arguments = ["-Xnosplash", jnlp];
        process.runwAsync(arguments, arguments.length);
   },

    exit : function() {
        process.kill();
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", loadingMonitor.launchExternalApp, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", loadingMonitor.exit, false);
```

I have tried logging so I know that exit is being called but if I try to print any of the information about the process I get undefineds, nulls, 0, etc.

I've followed [the API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProcess) and have been looking at bug reports but seemed to have reached a dead end.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this quite easily by oppening a socket to my java app and have that kill itself then System.exit(1);